# How to write recursive query executable by SSAS?

Tags: .net, ssas

I have a situation when I'd need to write a recursive query to be executed as a Named Query in SSAS, I couldn't use CTE in there? Is there any alternative except for changing the Database Model?

Comment: Why downvoted, why not put a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the query a view in SQL Server and then add the view to the SSAS data source view through the Add/Remove tables option.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I am having is I can't modify my database, having said that, I can't put anything in the database, view, table etc.